# Performance issue with Asus netbook

Tags: asus, eeepc

I've installed Ubuntu 14.02 LTS on my Asus netbook (Eee PC). I have slow responses on the desktop, and the video play back is juddering. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess I would say you need to install the closed source video drivers.

Type : Additional Drivers in the Dash.